# How to implement T-SQL table variable in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, datatables

I want to introduce T-SQL **table variable** in Python. I have created a list and its elements are dictionaries. So 1 element = 1 row in T-SQL.

In my T-SQL code I have.

```
declare @tmp_policy table(rnm int identity, polid int, num int, opendate DATETIME)
```

In my Python code I try like this.

```
tmp_policy = [
            {
                "rnm": 1,
                "polid": None,
                "num": None,
                "opendate": None
            }]
```

And append one element like this.

```
 tmp_policy.append({
                "rnm": len(tmp_policy)+1,
                "polid": pol_p[0]['ID'],
                "num": 0,
                "opendate": pol_p[0]['OPENDATE']
            })
```

Am I on the right way?

Comment: Are you on the right path, does it work when you try it? Please post the rest of your code too.

Comment: A Table Valued Parameter needs to be based on a Table Type, you cannot just use a `declare @tbl as table`

Comment: Look.  I have a T-SQL code and Python Project separately. And I am "translating"  T-SQL to Python (Django).  And I met some table variables in it.

The problem is... How to comulate some data in python to pretend the same as Table variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of dataframe is more likely similar with SQL-Server tables. It can be used by installing `pandas` module in your python environment.

[Installation pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html)

For example, the following python code is maybe what you want.

```all
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

tmp_policy = pd.DataFrame(data=None,
                          columns=['rnm', 'polid', 'num', 'opendate'],
                          ).convert_dtypes({
                              'rnm': int,
                              'polid': int,
                              'num': int,
                              'opendate': datetime
                          })

tmp_policy['rnm']=[i for i in range(1,len(pol_p['ID'])+1)]
tmp_policy['polid']=pol_p['ID']
tmp_policy['num']=0
tmp_policy['opendate']=pol_p['OPENDATE']
```